# Mapbox Android SDK will be deprecated

Tags: mapbox

The android sdk README says that mapbox-gl-native will substitute it. I suppose this will mean that you won't support raster based map views anymore, only vector tiles?

Answer (score 1):

mapbox-gl-native supports raster tiles as well as vector tiles. For streets, it renders vector data on-device, whereas for satellite or pre-existing raster tiles, it'll just show them like the Mapbox Android SDK does now.

Comment: On the iOS side, here's an example showing use of GL with raster tiles: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-ios/examples/raster-styles/